# Fail2Ban regex is wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

I'm currently setting up a filter to filter POST attacks on a file named `xmlrpc.php`. Requests that should be monitored in the log access look like:

```
1.99.437.201 - - [01/Feb/2016:01:57:14 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 631 "-" "curl/7.30.0"
```

The jail looks like:

```
[xmlrpc]
enabled = true
filter = xmlrpc
action = iptables[name=xmlrpc, port=http, protocol=tcp]
logpath = /srv/www/logs/access.log
bantime = 43600
maxretry = 5
```

And my filter is:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .*POST .*xmlrpc\.php.*
ignoreregex =
```

I'm trying to figure way the regex isn't catching the log attempts. Any insight on what `<HOST>` actually represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<HOST>` regex is quite smart. Amongst other things it knows that an IP address consists of 4 octets and each octet can have a value between 0 and 255. The IP address in your question 1.99.**437**.201 does not meet this specification and will not match a `<HOST>` regex. If you change the second octet to meet the specification then your regex works as expected

```
$ cat log
1.99.237.201 - - [01/Feb/2016:01:57:14 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 631 "-" "curl/7.30.0"

$ fail2ban-regex  log "^<HOST> .*POST .*xmlrpc\.php.*"

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^<HOST> .*POST .*xmlrpc\.php.*
Use         log file : log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] ^<HOST> .*POST .*xmlrpc\.php.*
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)Year[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed [processed in 0.00 sec]
```

Comment: +1 from me; nice catch!  I **do** hope that wasn't the OP trying to obscure an IP address for no good reason, and getting it wrong.

Comment: @MadHatter I can't see any other reason for it not to work. The OP is in London and posted this at 02:10, I suspect sleep deprivation.

Comment: @MadHatter I was changing my ip in order not to publish it online.  sleep deprivation confirmed and continues today

Comment: Sorry about the sleep deprivation.  Don't redact IP addresses; as you see, it is quite counterproductive.  See also e.g. [this meta answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6574/55514) for a longer justification.

Answer (score 0):

I use easier method to block all `xmlrpc.php` attacks.

Just place this code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This code will protect your Wordpress against all botnets.

Comment: I don't believe in this as they still hit your server and if you have several diff ip's hitting your machine it can get overloaded.  you need fail2ban to reject these requests from a specific IP attack